# Debug and Finding error in Bean Shell in Android

Tags: android, json, beanshell, pawserver

I'm using paw server and bean shell scripting in HTML which return the data in JSON form somehow I can't get any data from the script and I am not able to debug the script .

Here is the code

```
<bsh>
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;
import android.provider.Contacts.Phones;
import java.text.DateFormat;

service = server.props.get("serviceContext");
delete = parameters.get("delete");

SMS_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

// ArrayList for thread information
listThreads = new ArrayList();

URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");

// --- Thread IDs
cur = service.getContentResolver().query(URI, new String[] {"DISTINCT thread_id"}, null, null, "date DESC");
threadIDs = new ArrayList();
if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        threadIDs.add(cur.getInt(0));
    } while(cur.moveToNext());
}
cur.close();

print("[");
//--- Get infos

Integer it = 0;
for(id : threadIDs) {
    // ArrayList for this thread information
    listThreadInfo = new ArrayList();


   /* List content
      0: Thread ID (int)
      1: Address (String)
      2: Name (might be null) (String)
      3: Contact ID (might be 0) (int)
      4: Date (Date)
      5: Messages in Thread (int)
      6: Body (String)
      7: Unread messages (int)
   */

    // -- Messages in thread
    cur = service.getContentResolver().query(URI, new String[] { "COUNT(thread_id)" }, "thread_id=?", new String[] { "" + id }, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    count = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();

    // -- Unread messages
    cur = service.getContentResolver().query(URI, new String[] { "COUNT(read)" }, "thread_id=? AND read == 0", new String[] { "" + id }, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    unread = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();

    cur = service.getContentResolver().query(URI, null, "thread_id=?", new String[] { "" + id }, "date DESC LIMIT 1");
    if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contactId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("person"));
            address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            date = new Date(cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("date")));
            body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));

            // Only if address != null. Otherwise it's a DRAFT
            if(address != null) {

                name = null;

                phones = service.getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID },
                    android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=?", new String[] { address }, null
                );

                if(phones.moveToFirst()) {
                    contactId = phones.getInt(0);
                }

                phones.close();

                if(contactId != 0) {

                    contact = service.getContentResolver().query(
                        android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME }, 
                        android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + 
                        android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIMETYPE + "=?", new String[] { "" + contactId, android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, null
                    );

                    if(contact.moveToFirst()) {
                        name = contact.getString(0);
                    }

                    contact.close();
                }

                listThreadInfo.add(0, id);
                listThreadInfo.add(1, address);
                listThreadInfo.add(2, name);
                listThreadInfo.add(3, contactId);
                listThreadInfo.add(4, date);
                listThreadInfo.add(5, count);
                listThreadInfo.add(6, body);
                listThreadInfo.add(7, unread);

                body =  body.replace("\n", "<br>").replace("\t", "    ").replace("\"", "\\\"");

                print("{");
                print("\t\"id\" : " + id + ",");
                print("\t\"addr\" : \"" + address + "\",");
                print("\t\"name\" : \"" + name + "\",");
                print("\t\"contactId\" : " + contactId+ ",");
                print("\t\"date\" : " + date.getTime() + ",");
                print("\t\"count\" : " + count + ",");
                print("\t\"body\" : \"" + body + "\",");
                print("\t\"img\" : \"graphics/seeContactImg.xhtml?contactId=" + contactId + "\",");
                print("\t\"unread\" : " + unread);
                print("}");

                it++;
                if(it < threadIDs.size()) {
                    print(",");
                }
                listThreads.add(listThreadInfo);
            }
        } while(cur.moveToNext());
    }
    cur.close();
}
print("]");
</bsh>
```

The following code return sms in json form .There is something wrong in it but Im not able to debug because it is written in .xhtml form

Comment: Please be specific. What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested on a LG G4 running Android 6.0 and it worked without errors.
If there would be an exception it would be displayed inside the page source.
To get a more verbose error message you can use the ***debug*** parameter of the BeanShell handler inside the *conf/handler.xml* configuration file:

```
<handler status="active">
    <name>BeanShell Handler</name>
    <description>BeanShell Handler</description>
    <removable>true</removable>
    <id>bsh</id>
    <files />
    <params>
      <param name="bsh.class" value="org.paw.handler.BeanShellFileHandler" />
      <param name="bsh.debug" value="true" />
      <param name="bsh.root" value="[PAW_HOME]/html" />
      <param name="bsh.suffix" value=".xhtml" />
      <param name="bsh.default" value="index.xhtml" />
    </params>
  </handler>
```